# What proof is there that the "Island of Stability" exists?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, periodic-trends, periodic-table

Often I see people talking about an "Island of Stability" existing for super-heavy elements on the periodic table, but I don't see any reason to thinks this exists? Surely the heavier you go the more unstable nuclei get? What, if any, proof or theory is there behind expecting an "Island of Stability" to exist?

Comment: The theory is that certain numbers of protons and neutrons are "better" than the others. As for the proof, there is none. The island may just as well not be there, or be "completely underwater".

Comment: People often misread "theory" as "proof"...

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/