Cause of radioactivity in C-14
We all know that C-14 is highly radioactive. Whereas C-12 isn't. At the atomic scale, if we observe, the only difference between them is that C-14 has 2 more neutrons than C-12. And the neutrons act like a wall between protons to prevent proton-proton repulsion.
So, what causes radioactivity, as there are just 2 more neutrons?

All nuclides with the nucleon number 12 (isobars) are radioactive except $\ce{^{12}_6C}$ with p/n ratio 1:1 with the minimum of energy.  All nuclides with the nucleon number 14  are radioactive except $\ce{^{14}_7N}$ with p/n ratio 1:1 with the minimum of energy.  // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Just 2 more neutrons? Even one more is usually enough to turn stable isotope to unstable.

C-14 is not highly radioactive. You have a bunch in you right now and are not glowing. And, just for fun, nuclear physics considers the proton and neutron as pretty much the same beast, differing in isospin - that is, what was a proton a moment ago may now be a neutron while some other neutron just became a proton. Weird stuff at that level.

@JonCuster Hmm, bunch.... A human body may contain 10-15 ng of carbon-14. If you had a piece of carbon-14 coal in your pocket, you would be glowing.

@Poutnik - agreed. But there are many isotopes you would not like to have 15 ng of in your pocket even. The 5000 year half life pretty much means it is not 'highly' radioactive.

@JonCuster It depends on what you compare it to. Comparing it to potassium-40,  or with tellurium-128 with half-line in order of $\pu{E24}$ years, it is highly radioactive. It is comparable to radium-226. Not many people would say radium is not highly radioactive.

@Poutnik - not compared with isotopes with half lives in the days or less - those are highly radioactive. In nuclear fallout, nobody cares about carbon-14.

@JonCuster Nobody spoke about nuclear fallout. All depends on context. In some context it is highly radioactive, in some other context it is not.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/why-is-an-atom-with-excess-neutrons-unstable

Using the difference in nuclear mass and the hakf-life of 5730 years, I calcukate that 1 kg of C-14 emits about four watts of radiant power. Rather dim glow unless you're efficient at converting to light.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158100/neutron-proton-ratio-and-isotope-stability

Neutrons tend to dilute electrostatic repulsions, but for small nuclei the strong nuclear force, or residual strong interaction is the dominant interaction. We need larger nuclei for electrostatic repulsion to become competitive and favor neutrons over protons.
Put very roughly, the strong nuclear force favors proton-neutron binding over proton-proton or neutron-neutron binding. Put a proton and a neutron together and a particle that carries the strong nuclear force, called a meson, will be exchanged between them to convert the original neutron to a proton and vice versa. Trying a meson exchange with two protons doesn't work as well; you would have to produce a double-charged particle that requires more energy than a proton or neutron. A neutron-neutron meson exchange would also force a more energy-costly particle.
So the strong nuclear force alone favors maximizing possible proton-neutron interactions, thus equal counts of protons and neutrons. Thus, for example, nitrogen-14 is favored over carbon-14. For larger nuclei, however, the weaker but longer-range electrostatic repulsion finally becomes competitive, and we start seeing stable nuclei systematically having more neutrons than protons.

And  the instability of beryllium-8 is down to just how stable helium-4 is.
